# How to define the controller when changing a rails app to ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a simple rails app that works fine but I want to change it to use ajax. I have upgraded other parts using Ajax but I am having trouble with the controller code. So:

1) I have added the remote: true to the form_for.

2) I am having trouble with the controller code. Currently it looks like this:

```
def create #saving new materials
    @material = Material.new(params[:material])
    @material.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
    if @material.save
      flash[:success] = "Content Successfully Created"
      redirect_to @material
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

The problem is that I know I need a respond_to block but I don't know where to put it. I'm a novice so apologies if this is a stupid question.

FYI - The js code is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work :

```
def create #saving new materials
  @material = Material.new(params[:material])
  @material.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    if @material.save
      flash[:success] = "Content Successfully Created"
      format.html { redirect_to @material }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render 'new' }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```